# can't configure RabbitMQ , We are in process of deploying Rabbitmq clustering in our windows environment

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

i am fresh towards MQ’s, We are in process of deploying Rabbitmq clustering in our windows environment.
Can you please advise if its recommended to work with windows environment for RMQ?

Comment: You should direct such questions to the rabbitmq-users Google group.

Comment: This is probably not a good question for SO as RabbitMQ supports Windows and they even provide a guide on their website: [https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html].